# How can I setup Transmit along with Sidestep?

Tags: proxy, ftp

I'm using [Sidestep](http://chetansurpur.com/projects/sidestep/) to securely connect the Internet from everywhere I am. I have my own server as an SSH proxy.

But I'm facing trouble with [Transmit](http://www.panic.com/transmit) which doesn't seem to use the proxy settings defined by Sitestep.

I know there are some options available in Transmit to configure a proxy server, but since I really don't know much about proxy, SOCKS and stuff. I didn't succeed.

From all my tests, Transmit always seems to use the direct connection without going through the proxy.

Any hints?

Thanks,

Jérémy

Comment: Did you ask the folks at Panic? They're usually pretty good about helping out with stuff like this. http://www.panic.com/transmit/support.html

Comment: Yep did it, a few days ago. I pretty sure they will answser. But I'm in a hurry, so any fast anwser is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here it is: https://github.com/chetan51/sidestep/issues/34#issuecomment-3137335

In Transmit define

- Proxy Type: SOCK 5
- Proxy Host: 127.0.0.1
- Proxy Port: 9050